# Count Up Animation when element is visible for the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i have a problem, the counting animation  im using now on multiple elements, only starts once for the first element.

And im also trying to set the "counting-to"-value in the html. is there is an easy way to load them into the js for each element?

in the end im trying to get the counting up animation starting when the div is visible for the user by scrolling down. when its visible it should stay as it is after running the animation once.

Only if the user scroll the element out of the visibility, then it should reset and starting again if its get visible again.

Has anybody an idea how i can solved that?

heres the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/drfux88/aJrj4/32/

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var range = end - start;
    var minTimer = 50;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = startTime + duration;
    var timer;

    function run() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
        var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
        obj.innerHTML = value;
        if (value == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
    run();
}

animateValue("value", 0, 75, 2000);
```

Comment: need to present relevant code here in question...not in a remote site link where people will have to dig through files to try to figure out where code might be

Comment: Please post your code here instead of linking a webpage

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the element once the animation starts the first time, and then select that element using a :not selector. For example, select the animation div like so:

```
$('.animation_div:not(.animating)');
```

Then later when the animation starts:

```
$('.animation_div').addClass('animating');
```